# Excluding sheets in readxl

Tags: r, readxl

I have data that comes in Excel spreadsheets, with a varying number of sheets. Rather than reading all the sheets, as has been explained elsewhere, I would like to exclude the first sheet when importing into R using the readxl package. Using the example data in the package:

```
library("readxl")
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xls")
lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)
```

If I wanted to read all but the first sheet in this data set, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You're probably going to need to loop through the paths and read in the next sheet until you find one with dim = 0,0, then iterate to the next file.

Comment: Does this do what you want : `lapply(excel_sheets(path)[-1], read_excel, path = path)` ?

Comment: Remko - that does exactly what I asked for!  If you post it as an answer, I will check it. Svenhalvorson, that might be a good solution for me, as I also need to rename both the sheet and the column.  I figured out how to do that individually, but I'm not sure whether that can be done in lapply, or whether a loop would be better.  Thank you both!